# How can I use Rspec to test that a model using Paperclip is validating the size of an uploaded file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip

The model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :narrative

  attr_accessible :description, :user_id, :narrative_id

  has_attached_file :file

  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_presence_of :narrative_id
  validates_attachment :file, :presence => true,
                       :size => {:less_than => 20.megabytes}
end
```

The test which doesn't work:

```
describe Attachment do
  it { should validate_presence_of :file }
  it { should validate_size_of :file } # validate_size_of does not exist
end
```

I would like to avoid dumping a 20 MB file into the repo just to test this. Is there a way similar to the one I tried above that will actually work?

Comment: add a mock for file and it's function size should do the trick

Comment: I guess you are using `shoulda-matchers` which do not already have the validate_size_of matcher built in for obvious reasons.

The second thing is that I am afraid you would need to write the test crudely as you mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way I've done this is to use the built-in [shoulda matchers for Paperclip](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Shoulda/Matchers). The documentation at that link is really good, but here's an overview from the docs of what you can do with it:

In spec_helper.rb, you'll need to require the matchers:

```
require "paperclip/matchers"
```

And include the module:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
end
```

Example that validates the attachment size:

```
describe User do
  it { should validate_attachment_size(:avatar).
                less_than(2.megabytes) }
end
```

If you're interested, the source for the matchers can be [found on GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master/lib/paperclip/matchers)

Comment: Thanks. I'd not gotten the include bit in spec_helper.