# Undefined method `[]' for paperclip validation matcher with rspec3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip, rspec3

I'm using paperclip-4.2.0+rspec 3.0.3 with rails 4.1.4 and wrote rspec for paperclip attachment size validation and the following problem happen

```
Failure/Error: it { should validate_attachment_size(:image).less_than(8.megabytes) }
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I followed the solution from [How can I use Rspec to test that a model using Paperclip is validating the size of an uploaded file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789060/how-can-i-use-rspec-to-test-that-a-model-using-paperclip-is-validating-the-size) but still facing this problem can anyone help me...